# Phpunit shows errors in random test cases while running all the tests together

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, phpunit

I have made a number of test cases on PHPUnit for Browser testing of the website, all these tests pass when I run them individually , but when I try to run them as a group or using `php artisan dusk` command, some of them fail. The real problem is that whenever I run them together, **error occurs in different test cases every time.**
I searched it on the internet and found `RefreshDatabase` and `DatabaseTransaction` commands but I can't use them as it is not a suitable solution and also not allowed by my colleagues. Kindly let me know what I'm missing or what else I should add in order to run all the tests smoothly.
P.S.I want to run them together for Auto-deployment on servers **(testing and then deploying the changes)**

Below is an example test for clear understanding of the issue:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class AddUsrSegmentTest extends DuskTestCase
{
     

    /**
     * create a user segment
     *
     * @return void
     * @group other
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
              $browser->loginAs(\App\Model\User::find(4567))
              ->visit('/home')
           
              ->clickLink('Create From Scratch')

              ->assertPathis('/bot/dashboard')
                //first create a user datastore
                   ->visit('/bot/datastore')
              ->assertSee('Create a Global/User Datastore')
              ->visit('/bot/datastore/create')
              ->assertSee('Custom Values')
              ->click('#showCustomInput')
              ->type('key','colorsss')    
              //->type('.bootstrap-tagsinput > input:nth-child(1)','apple')
              //->keys('.bootstrap-tagsinput > input:nth-child(1)','mango', ['{enter}'])
              ->keys('.bootstrap-tagsinput > input:nth-child(1)','green', ['{enter}'],'mustard',['{enter}'],'blue',['{enter}'],'red',['{enter}'])


              

              ->click('.slider')

              ->assertSee('Add Datastore')
              ->click('button.btn:nth-child(1)')// add datastore button
              ->visit('/bot/datastore')
              ->assertSeeIn('#zero-config','colorsss')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, what actions did you follow? What code did you try? Try to provide a minimal reproducible example so the community can better understand how to help you.

Comment: @SpyrosK I'm using laravel dusk for running browser tests. I will edit the question and provide an example test for better understanding.